# docker: mariadb replication on different host

Tags: mysql, docker, mariadb

I need to replicate my mariadb container to another host docker engine's mariadb container.
All the examples I found are replicating two mariadb inside a same host.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: What have you already tried? A person would need at least an hour to write a proper step-by-step for this process, explaining elements of Docker and how SQL replication works along the way. If you've already started down the process, the steps could be drastically reduced, making it much more likely that someone will offer suggestions on how to make this work 

Comment: @Matigo Hello sir, I now have two mariadb docker container from two different hosts. im stuck in stablishing a connection between them making one the master and the other as the slave.